# How to bind and ConvertBack separated TextBox strings to an ObservableCollection<string>?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, binding

I have view-model with `ObservableCollection<string>` that's bound to a `TextBox`. Users must be able to enter textual data with some separators (say a comma or a semicolon), and have the change reflected to the `ObservableCollection<string>`, so if I type in the box `abc,123,one`, the `ObservableCollection<string>` will have three items: `abc`, `123` and `one`.

My examplary ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyObservableCollection { get; set; }
}
```

My TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyObservableCollection, Converter={StaticResource Conv}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

My value-converter:

```
public class ObservableCollectionToAndFromString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> oc;
        if (targetType != typeof (string) || (oc = value as ObservableCollection<string>) == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        return string.Join(",", oc);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        return str == null
            ? Binding.DoNothing
            : str.Split(',');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work from understandable reason - WPF doesn't know how to replace an `ObservableCollection<string>` with `string[]`.

But I don't want the framework to replace my `ObservableCollection<string>` object with new `ObservableCollection<string>` object (in that case I could have just created new one and return it in the `ConvertBack` method). I want it to add/remove items to/from the existing `ObservableCollection<string>`.

How can I accomplish this (without another model-view `string` property that will do the work in code-behind)?

## Edit:

Ok, I give up... movel-view is the way to go... I hoped to make it work on several fields in one time, but that just to awkward.

Comment: `ConvertBack` should always return a new object. That's how it's designed. I don't see why returning a new object can be a problem here. The reference to the old collection would be collected by GC automatically at the right time, so you should not worry about memory leak...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to add a string representation of data to your viewmodel.

```
internal class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyObservableCollection { get; set; }

    public string MyString
    {
        get { return string.Join(",", MyObservableCollection); }
        set { // update observable collection here based on value }
    }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: This is my current solution, but I'm not happy with it. The extra field and lack of generalization bothers me... (yes, this is what view-model is for, @Dennis, but I'd be happy to apply this solution to other places as well and on many fields with one stroke...)

Comment: @Tal Your view model should provide data which is easy to consume by your view. If you're building something complex (and you'll have to jump through hoops to achieve it), you're doing it wrong. It can't be done with just a converter.

Comment: As @Dennis mentions that is why we have a view model layer. So we can adapt the data to the presentation layer. So you shouldn't be bothered using it that way.

Comment: @Tal: search this in the web - "A ViewModel is basically a value converter on steroids", you'll find rather interesting reading.